# How to find the the sum of the finite series $ \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{n-k+1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to find the the sum of the finite series $ \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{n-k+1}$ ?

If I expand the series then, we get

$ \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{n-k+1}=\frac{1}{2-k}+\frac{1}{3-k}+\cdots+\frac{1}{N-k}$.

How to sum it.

Here $N,k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$.

Is there any short or closed form of it in terms of probably $N, k$?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to see this serie as a Riemann integral ?

Comment: @Pastudent, how exactly it helps us? Can you show work?

Comment: Do you know about harmonic numbers ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR MY method gives a result, but only in the infinite case. So i am not of any use.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I know harmonic series but don't know harmonic numbers

Comment: @Pastudent, In infinite case how do you do this?

Comment: Let me re-check that it works.

Comment: My bad, misread the post.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, please help me with some small work as hints

Comment: If you know the *Digamma function* $\psi(x)$ you can use for your sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n+x}=\psi(N+x)-\psi(x)$ .

Comment: The harmonic series is in reference to $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.  The harmonic *numbers* is in reference to the sequence of partial sums of the harmonic series, the $k$'th harmonic number being $H(k) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}$.  You can then also talk about generalized harmonic numbers and whatnot too.  As for having a cleaner solution than writing it in terms of the digamma function or harmonic numbers (which are closely related), I wouldn't think so.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I did not get the clear meaning of your last line. Are you saying to use digamma or harmonic series for clear or exact form? But how to use harmonic number ? Because I have a shift by $(-k)$ as look in $\frac{1}{N-k}$

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR "How to use harmonic number?"  Simply's answer below already shows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no closed form in terms of elementary functions. In terms of the harmonic numbers, defined by

$$H_m=\sum_{n=1}^m\frac1n$$

we have

$$H_{N-k}-H_{1-k}=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac1{n-k+1}$$

supposing that $k$ is a negative integer. For non-integer $k$, we can use the above as generalized harmonic numbers defined by

$$H_x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+x}\right)$$

or equivalent, such as the digamma function, Hurwitz zeta function, etc.

Comment: Here $k, N$ all are integers. Actually for my research I need some compact form involving $N,k$. Do Digamma function help ?

Comment: If $k$ is a negative integer, you can simply use the first definition of the harmonic numbers. And I can't tell you if the digamma function would help you or not, as I don't know what you're working on.

Comment: Sorry, here $k,N$ all are whole numbers. Can not be negative. Also I used bracket in your answer. can you check it ?

Comment: if $N\ge k$ the sum is undefined. Otherwise you can use pretty much the same thing as I have done, except sum it in reverse to get:$$H_{k-1}-H_{k-N}=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac1{n-k+1}$$

Comment: So, how does we compute the harmonic numbers $H_{k-N}$ ? Does this harmonic numbers posses any value?

Comment: Using the provided definition(s) in my answer? Unless you meant something different than simply "computing"?

Comment: Beautiful, If I had $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{k}{n-k+1}$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{n-k+1}$, then how do I proceed ?

Comment: That's just literally the same thing but multiplied by $k$?